# WHen i open terminal, i get a malloc error that shuts it down. mac os 10.8.2

Tags: mac, terminal

WHen i launch terminal, i get an error that says

> BlockquoteLast login: Wed Nov 14 14:54:37 on console
>   login(1943,0x7fff72328180) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fa50c0006f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

[Process completed]
i cant even use terminal, please help!

Answer (score 9):

Someone or something mucked with file permissions. Open Disk Utility. From the Applications folder, open Utilities, and then double-click the Disk Utility icon. In the column on the left, click on your startup disk. Select the First Aid tab, and then click Repair Disk Permissions. (Seeing some errors or warnings during this process is normal.)